# two external hard drives simultaniously

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive

I have two external western digital usb3 hard drives connected simultaniously to my windows 7 system. I can use them just normally in windows explorer and all is fine.

However I want to use one of them as my backup volume, the other one is my media drive.

I tried two different backup software, both are suffering from the same problem: Losing connection to the backup drive and trying to backup to the media drive.
It's always the same problem, the inital backup goes to the right drive, the further backups goes to the media volume.

Both drives have of course their own drive letter and they are both online in the drive manager so I assume this is not a signature ID problem. But they get still confused by the software somehow.

Is there anything to fix this behavior? Thanx in advance.

*edit:* Both drives are connected permanently and no other software has shown any problems so far. Windows is assigning them always the same drive letters (k: and y:) and I just checked that their signatures are different with `diskpart`. The backup software was `genie time line` and `oops!backup`.

*edit2:* Both softwares proudly advertising that they are able to find the correct backup drive, even when the drive letter changes. I did some debugging yesterday and found that this feature is simply not working. Problem is one cannot configure to not use it or just use drive letters. I found that the programs just use whatever drive comes first (drive letter wise). I configured the backup volume before the media volume and now everything works. It must be coincidence that this problem occurs by both softwares. I also tried two other backup softwares which don't have this problem so I really think it's just a bug. Thanks for all effort guys, I'm done with this.

Comment: What backup software are you using?  How do you identify the drive in the software settings?  Are the drives "permanently" connected or do you periodically plug/unplug them?  Does the system always assign them the same drive letter, even if you leave them plugged in?

Comment: @fixer1234 edited my post with the answers.

Comment: Can you rule out any problem with the backup drive, itself (or cable or port)?  Is the software just selecting a different drive for no apparent reason or when this happens, does the OS also fail to detect the drive?  When you say "losing connection to the drive", are you talking figuratively or you've diagnosed that the drive can't be seen?  If you restart the software after the failure, does it see/use the drive again?  What is it that allows the next initial backup to use the right drive (e.g., reboot)?  Does the software provide any diagnostic messages?

Comment: If one program messes up, can you immediately start the other and have it work correctly?  When you talk about initial backup vs. further backups, are you talking about one right after the other, or say on different days with a reboot in between?  Is there plenty of free space on the backup drive?

Comment: It seems there is no apparent reason for the software to change drives. The backup volume is fresh and has plenty of free space. Also it stays online in windows explorer and accessable in explorer by me. By "initial backup" I meant the very first backup. All others with or wihout reboot went to the media drive. The software triggers the next backups after a few minutes (files changed etc) causing this behavior. I thought it might be a bug in the program so I was trying another software. To my surprise with the same problems. I only have one program installed at the time not both at the same.

Comment: Also I could not find any debug loggings so far. I will check tomorrow if I can find anything useful.

Comment: If you're backing up specific directories, there is typically a backup "profile" that specifies the source and target.  Does that remain correct but the software uses the wrong drive, or is the target specified in the profile changing?  Does the software provide a "progress report" on what it's doing, and does that refer to the correct or incorrect target (e.g., says it writing to the backup drive but it's actually going to the media drive)?

Comment: Do these drives happen to have the same volume label? Some backup software binds to the label rather than hardware sig. Alternatively, they may be not relying on GPT/MBR IDs (shown by `diskpart`) but be computing their own and *these* might happen to be the same for these drives... though chances of this happening with two independent apps is pretty slim :-?

Comment: The volume label is different. It might be that they are computing there own IDs. Maybe I will check this one time.
I edited the question but I'm through with this for now. Thanks guys!